# Nested Objects: Android Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

```
@Entity(tableName="user_table")
data class User(
   @PriamryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id:Int,
   @Embeded(prefix="address_") val address:Address
)
@Entity(tableName = "address_table")
data class Address(
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id:Int
)
```

Is there a way to just ignore the Id column from Address table because from my knowledge I will be getting 
columns `id, address_id` in the user object once created
I have similar columns here and there and some are no longer in use once I create views for these tables i.e foreign keys etc

Comment: Are you trying to save a custom object to the room DB?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to just ignore the Id column from Address.

I don't believe so. Assuming that Address has other fields (otherwise simply don't Embed) then to Embed an Entity with an Entity is de-normalising the database.

If you have decided that you don't need to store the addresses in a seperate table as there is effectively a 1-1 relationship then you should do away with the address table, which could/would be converting the Address class to not be an Entity and remove the id field.

If you were to keep the Address class as an Entity then you cannot @Ignore the @PrimaryKey as Room requires that an Entity has an @PrimaryKey. Really, in this situation of having another table for the address, you should reference/map the address to not de-normalise and thus just have a field in the user_table for that reference/mapping rather than Embed. You would/could then have a non-entity class (POJO) for extracting data that would use Embed both Entities or Embed one and Relate the other.

Comment: Thanks. Was thinking something more of in the lanes of `@Embeded(ignore=[columnsToBeIgnoredOn ember])` 
This was a problem when creating views as the Address table is used in more than one place made sense not to repeat those columns in other tables.